# From string convert to list of list

Tags: java, android, list

I have list of lists like this: `[[foo, bar], [foo, bar]]`. And created like this:

```
List<String> listOfString = new ArrayList<String>();

    listOfString.add("foo");
    listOfString.add("bar");

    String value = listOfString.get(0);
    List<List> listOfArray = new ArrayList<List>();
    listOfArray.add(listOfString);
    listOfArray.add(listOfString);
```

Then I converting that list to string and send to server. Then I get response also in string I want to convert that string back to list of lists. Ho I could solve it?

Comment: looks like the the response you are sending to the server and you getting is in JSON format . if its true try to search how to modify JSON data in java

Comment: Regardless of whether it's JSON or not, what you want to do to the string is called _parsing_ it.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).  If it's JSON, then there are parsers out there that you can use.  If not, then you may have to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

One iteration way:

- create your main list of lists
- iterate over each character in response
- when you find inner `[` create new temporary `ArrayList` for data in this `[..]` portion,
- read next characters and store them in some buffer
- each time you find `,` or `]` put currently characters from buffer to temporary list you previously created (also clear buffer)
- when you find inner `]` add current temporary list to your main list